# Populate list with loop

Tags: python

I am trying to populate a list with numbers given via input.

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = []
```

The desired result would be if I entered 3 different numbers 10, 15, 5 that it would print `[10,15,5]`.

The book I'm using does not really explain how to do this, so it's kind of frustrating.

Comment: It's generally much cleaner and faster to do this kind of thing with a list comprehension, but I assume you're asking as a learning exercise?

Comment: Yea it's an exercise in the book. It's an online text.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; where is your attempt, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: do you want to just print it if those are different ?

Answer (score 4):

> Write a loop to populate the list user_guesses with a number of
> guesses. The variable num_guesses is the number of guesses the user
> will have, which is read first as an integer. Read integers one at a
> time using int(input()).

```
num_guesses = int(input())
user_guesses = []
for i in range(num_guesses):
    user_guesses.append(int(input()))


print('user_guesses:', user_guesses)
```

> Sample output with input: '3 9 5 2' user_guesses: [9, 5, 2]

Answer (score 2):

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = [int(raw_input()) for _ in range(num_guesses)]


In [31]: num_guesses = 3   
In [32]: user_guesses = [int(raw_input()) for _ in range(num_guesses)]
10
15
5    
In [33]: user_guesses
Out[33]: [10, 15, 5]
```

Comment: @royhowie, probably a try/except would be the correct way to go but that would be another question!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
num_guesses = 3
my_list = []
guess = 0
while guess < num_guesses:
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    my_list.append(num)
    guess += 1

print my_list
```

Comment: This works, but you can remove guesses and just use the length of the list.

Comment: True, but I find this easier to understand for new people.
I know `my_list = [int(input('Enter a number: ')) for _ in range(num_guesses)]` is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest for understand is using a `for` loop like this:

```
num_guesses = 3
user_guesses = []

for i in range(num_guesses):    # I here goes from 0 to 2.
    user_guesses.append(int(raw_input())) #for python 3 just use input

print(user_guessess)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to do is read in user input and append it to a list:

```
input = input("Guess:")
user_guesses.append(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_guesses = int(input())  # user input

user_guesses = []          # empty list to populate


for i in range(0, num_guesses):  # first user input of how many guesses they get

    user_guess = int(input())  # new variable that takes the remaining user input

    user_guesses.append(user_guess)  # append(user_guess) adds input to list
        

print('user_guesses:', user_guesses) # prints users guesses
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).